# Time dilation near a black hole

Tags: gravity, black-holes, time-dilation

If an Object exists near a black hole where 1 hour of its time is observed by a distant observer as 10 hours, then is total amount of light emitted by Object (in that one hour) toward the distant observer spread out over the 10 hours as seen by the observer?

Answer (score 1):

Yes. You can imagine it sending the light in discrete pulses at regular times, and they will arrive regularly but more slowly.

Comment: Is the reverse also true? Would ten hours of light from the observer arriving at the Object in one hour make that light appear brighter (and blue shifted) at the Object?

Comment: @A.Carris - Yes. As shown  in appendix 9A in Hobson, Efstathiou & Lasenby General Relativity: An Introduction for Physicists (2006) the redshif (or blueshift) between an emitter and receiver in a static spacetime is $\nu_{R}/\nu_{E} = \sqrt{g_{00}(E)/g_{00}(R)}$ - if you switch the roles the redshift becomes a blueshift.